# ¿ Cómo puedo enumerar una tabla dinámica en power bi?

Tags: powerbi

Estoy creando un Dashboard. Y quiero rankear las las posiciones según la posición. ¿Cómo lo hago?. En la tabla que tengo, quiero que aparezca las posiciones cuando lo ordeno de mayor a menor [image: Una tabla dinámica en power bi]

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que tienes tu consulta ya en Power Query, te vas al apartado de transformar datos de la pestaña **inicio**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Abrirá otra ventana mostrando los datos que tienes hasta el momento, ve a las pestaña **agregar columna** y da en **columna de indice** y **desde 1**, con eso genera el indice para los registros que tienes.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Te genera una columna así, según la cantidad de registros.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dime si te sirvió.

Comment: Lo que tengo es una tabla que se crea en las visualizaciones

Comment: Con esa descripción imposible ayudarte, edita tu pregunta dando mas detalle de la tabla y como es que la generaste.